# Linux ubuntu how to stop cron status mails like "Cron <root@ip-myip> /usr/bin/php /var/www/myproject"

Tags: linux, email, ubuntu, cron

Since couple of days i'm getting unwanted cron status emails from my server.
Tried MAILTO="" but still receiving mails.
Please help me to get rid of this emails.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cron` will email you anything that appears on stdout, so redirect stdout to /dev/null in your crontab entries. eg:

```
5 21 * * 1-5  { echo stuff to do; } >&/dev/null
```